# Issues with script - If condition not met, j += 1, once condition met, j = 0, i += 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, variables, while-loop

I am writing an accounting program that works with openpyxl to create journal entries in Excel format. I am at the point where I am trying to create a loop that loops through two variables.

This is what I want the loop to do: If the first condition is met: post the journal entry and reset j to 0. If the second condition is met add 1 to j and try the first condition again. Once the first condition is met add one to i. Essentially i represents the journal entry to post, j represents a list of Excel cells I want the journal to post to. So if the first cell is occupied, post the journal to the second cell, etc., and once it finds an empty cell post the journal entry and move on to the next one.

```
def journalEntries():
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < (len(debitname)):
        if int(monthpost[i]) == int(today.month) and journal[str(sheetNames[daypost[i] - 1])][str(debit[j])].value is None:
            journal[str(sheetNames[int(daypost[i]-1)])][str(debit[j])] = debitname[i]
            journal[str(sheetNames[int(daypost[i]-1)])][str(credit[j])] = creditname[i]
            journal[str(sheetNames[int(daypost[i]-1)])][str(debitamount[j])] = amounts[i]
            journal[str(sheetNames[int(daypost[i]-1)])][str(creditamount[j])] = amounts[i]
            j = 0
        elif int(monthpost[i]) == int(today.month) and journal[str(sheetNames[daypost[i] - 1])][str(debit[j])].value is not None:
            j += 1
        i += 1
    journal.save(journalPathtest)

journalEntries()
```

The above causes only a few entries to be posted. I am fairly certain the issue is where I am defining and incrementing i and j, I just can't figure out where to do it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: Heres the adjustment to the function that increments i in the right spot. Now the script is booking 1 days set of journal entries twice:

```
def journalEntries():
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < 30:
        if int(monthpost[i]) == int(today.month) and journal[str(sheetNames[daypost[i] - 1])][str(debit[j])].value is None:
            journal[str(sheetNames[int(daypost[i]-1)])][str(debit[j])] = debitname[i]
            journal[str(sheetNames[int(daypost[i]-1)])][str(credit[j])] = creditname[i]
            journal[str(sheetNames[int(daypost[i]-1)])][str(debitamount[j])] = amounts[i]
            journal[str(sheetNames[int(daypost[i]-1)])][str(creditamount[j])] = amounts[i]
            i += 1
            j = 0
        else:
            print("Trying next cell...")
            j += 1
    journal.save(journalPathtest)

journalEntries()
```

Comment: Move `i += 1` after `j = 0` inside the if-block, and change `elif ...` to just `else:`.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to increment i only if first condition is true

Comment: Getting close thanks! So now it runs through every entry I have saved in a list twice... Its almost like it takes two passes of the if statement to increment += 1... for example - 1 Excel tab will have Cell 1 - Entry 1 -/ Cell 2 - Entry 2 / Cell 3 - Entry 1 / Cell 4 - Entry 2

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - The i += 1 after the j =  0 works fine. I had to add a few additional conditions to skip over certain items in my lists of data so things weren't duplicated. Thanks for the help!

Answer:

```
def journalEntries():
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < int(len(debitname)):
        if debitname[i] == "Unreconciled":
            i += 1
        elif int(monthpost[i]) != int(today.month):
            i += 1
        elif int(monthpost[i]) == int(today.month) and journal[str(sheetNames[daypost[i] - 1])][str(debit[j])].value is None:
            journal[str(sheetNames[int(daypost[i]-1)])][str(debit[j])] = debitname[i]
            journal[str(sheetNames[int(daypost[i]-1)])][str(credit[j])] = creditname[i]
            journal[str(sheetNames[int(daypost[i]-1)])][str(debitamount[j])] = amounts[i]
            journal[str(sheetNames[int(daypost[i]-1)])][str(creditamount[j])] = amounts[i]
            i += 1
            j = 0
        else:
            print("Trying next cell...")
            j += 1
    journal.save(journalPathtest)

journalEntries()
```